# Object Pronoun vs Reflexive pronoun

Tags: pronouns

> Question 13:
>  She is too old. She can't look after herself, so she
> needs someone to look after _____.
>  A) herself
>  B) her
>  C)
> something
>  D) hers
>  E) nothing

The correct answer to the question above is B) her. However, I think "herself" can also be correct. But I am not sure if it has the same meaning.

Comment: No, you *can't* use ***herself*** in the cited context. We only use reflexive pronouns in contexts where the "agent" and the "patient" (verb "subject" and "object") are ***the same person***.

Comment: As @FumbleFingers points out, reflexive pronouns are for use when the agent and patient coincide. In your sentence, although *she* is the grammatical subject of the verb *need*, the verb that governs here is *take care of*, and the subject of that verb is *someone*.  It would do the old woman little good if that someone were too busy taking care of **themselves** to bother tending to her.

Comment: She is too old. She can't look after herself, so she needs someone 1)(to look after herself means who can look  after herself ( it does not make any sense) 2)but to look after her means who can look after the her(actual subject) because she is too old(it makes sense).

Comment: Thanks a lot, everybody.